# FIXED - XCode Swift - Dismissing keyboard on return key press doesn't do anything

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to have the keyboard dismiss when clicking the return key on the keyb board when using a UITextField. The class is set with the UITextFieldDelegate, I am setting the textfield's delegate to self and also have the textFieldShouldReturn function. With all this, I am still unable to get it to work.

EDIT: After trying with a print statement, the textFieldShouldReturn function is not being called at all.
After removing all other code from the view controller except the one below, it started working. My only clue to why would be due to me using self.loadview() in viewWillAppear and viewDidDissapear, might this be the case?

**FIXED:** problem was due to using self.loadview(). After changing that part of the code, everything started working properly.

Part of code for this function shown below.

```
class ConfigurationViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var storeNameVal: UITextField!

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true;
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        storeNameVal.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `textFieldShouldReturn` is calling?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini updated the question, the function is not being called

Comment: The code you've posted looks fine. Are you sure `storeNameVal` is never overwritten?

Comment: Are you sure the textField you are selecting is the `storeNameVal`?